# MySQL permission errors after macOS Sierra update

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, macos-sierra

First, phpmyadmin is throwing dozens of errors when I try to do anything from it. (images at the bottom)

Second, I tried creating a database from the command line and I got this:

```
mysql> create database support;
ERROR 13 (HY000): Can't get stat of './support' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

From some googling of this error, I tried the `\! pwd;` command, and for some reason it points to one of my projects in the Documents folder:

```
mysql> \! pwd;
/Users/username/Documents/project-name
```

Any idea what is wrong?

**Server version: 5.7.13 MySQL Community Server (GPL)**

Thanks

[image: phpmyadmin error 1]

[image: phpmyadmin error 2]

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Also after an update to Sierra) this was caused by the user running mysqld (The user mysql) being unable to open the mysql data directory with write permission. The files were instead owned by myself. I fixed this with:

```
sudo chown -R mysql /usr/local/mysql/*
```

The orignal cause (for me) was not the Sierra upgrade itelf, but the overall process of updating applications in response. Specifically that instructions for updating PHP with brew after the Sierra update had included a chown:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local     # DO NOT DO THIS
```

This had unfortunately altered the file permissions within /usr/local/mysql, causing the error that you found.